# how to pull current date and next date with one Query

Tags: sql

I have list of the dates where payments changes including next payment as well i need to pull what is my current date was changed and next date change of payments in a table

I have table where list of loans and when payments effective changes i can able to pull particular date giving the range but including next date i need current date as well

Comment: Please post your sample data and expected output.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Sample data will help

Comment: The lack of sample data and expected output makes your question almost unintelligible.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
     Select column, max(date_column) - 
      min(date_column) from table
     group by column
```